# How do i design Instagram like toggle on feed page to toggle between grid view and list view in Swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

After some reading, i came across lot of posts/articles where people have said that Instagram's Me/Profile page is `UITableView` ( because of sticky header ) and a `UICollectionView` inside to show photos in grid view on toggle.

I have the exact requirement. Right now my base view is a table view, with header view containing all other views like Profile data, options to Switch between grid view and list view.

How do i display images in grid view when user clicks on toggle button? And revert back to list view when toggle button is clicked again?

My First view will be grid view. So on load, i will set no. of rows in the table = 1 and add a collection view inside that row. 
When user clicks on toggle to show as list view, i will increase no. of rows in the table and use custom cell to populate with data.

**Is this the correct way to proceed?**

This is the initial screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can also just use a UICollectionView for both. Might be easier.

Comment: @AaronBrager if i use collectionView, how do i add some more views to the layout in list mode? For example, in grid view, I will just show the photos. In the list mode, I would need UI Elements like Like Count, etc, for each image. Do i have to change collectionLayout in list mode then?

Comment: Yeah, you would just use a different layout object and return different cells.

Comment: thanks @AaronBrager, I will try with UICollectionView and try to build this instead of using a UITableView and update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to design the layout completely using `UICollectioView` only. I have a collectionView with header. I am using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to decide how the view should look like in "Grid" and "List" Mode.

By default, I have a grid view. For that I have a custom UICollectionViewCell named `GridViewCell`.

When user clicks on List view, I deque custom UICollectionViewCell named `ListViewCell` that has UIElements laid out to seem like a List/Table view.

Thanks to @AaronBrager for guiding me to use UICollectionView and completely remove TableView

Answer (score 1):

**You need some properties**

```
CollectionViewGridFlowLayout *gridLayout;
CollectionViewTableFlowLayout *tableLayout;
BOOL onGrid; //if not we are in table mode
```

**You need to set up your datasource for each layout before you make the change**

```
-(void)changeLayoutButtonTapped {

    if (!onGrid) {
        [self loadDataForGridLayout]; //Your data preparation
    }
    else {
        [self loadDataForTableLayout]; //Your data preparation
    }

    [self animateState];
}
```

**Make your layout change**

```
-(void)animateState {

    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.15;
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout;

    // ADD SPIN ANIMATION TO CELLS FOR FUN
    [profileCollectionView.visibleCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UICollectionViewCell *cell, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
     {
         CABasicAnimation *translateXAnimation;
         translateXAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
         translateXAnimation.fromValue = @(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2);
         translateXAnimation.toValue = @(0);
         translateXAnimation.duration = duration*2;
         translateXAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

         CABasicAnimation *translateYAnimation;
         translateYAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
         translateYAnimation.fromValue = @(self.view.bounds.size.height);
         translateYAnimation.toValue = @(0);
         translateYAnimation.duration = duration*2;
         translateYAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

         CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation;
         opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
         opacityAnimation.fromValue = @(0);
         opacityAnimation.toValue = @(1);
         opacityAnimation.duration = duration*2;
         opacityAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

         [cell.layer addAnimation:translateXAnimation forKey:kCAAnimationCubicPaced];
         [cell.layer addAnimation:translateYAnimation forKey:kCAAnimationCubicPaced];
         [cell.layer addAnimation:opacityAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];

     }];


    // Toggle between layouts
    if (onGrid == NO) {

        // CHANGE TO GRID LAYOUT

        if (!gridLayout) {

            gridLayout = [[CollectionViewGridFlowLayout alloc]initWithContentSize:self.view.bounds.size cellPadding:7];
            gridLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, (kNavBarHeight + kTabBarHeight) + (kButtonHeight), 12);
        }

        layout = gridLayout;
    }

    else {

        // CHANGE TO TABLE LAYOUT         

        if (!tableLayout) {

            tableLayout = [[CollectionViewTableFlowLayout alloc]initWithContentSize:self.view.bounds.size cellHeight:85 cellPadding:12];
            tableLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, (kNavBarHeight + kTabBarHeight) + (kPostsListenButtonHeight + kPostsListenUnderLineHeight), 12);
        }

        layout = tableLayout;
    }

    // COMMIT ANIMATION
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration delay:0.01 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubicPaced animations:^{

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
        collectionView.scrollsToTop = YES;
        [collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (finished) {

            if (onGrid == NO) {
                onGrid = YES;
            }

            else {
                onGrid = NO;
            }
        }

    }];

}
```

Comment: what are CollectionViewGridFlowLayout and CollectionViewTableFlowLayout ? And you please add Swift equivalent code / snippets if you can

Comment: They are subclasses of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Make one for each layout that you want. Their main purpose is to sent the proportions of the cells for each layout. Sorry I wrote that for Objective-C. Works the same in swift. I gave you the answer, so if you can decipher the swift syntax version then thats not so much work, is it?

Comment: yeah, i can convert to swift. Will explore this. What do you suggest? Check comments under the question. I guess its better to go with UICollectionVIew  as main view rather than a UITableView right? This code is for UICollectionView. Got it.

Comment: Yes a `UICollectionView` is what you want. They are more powerful than `UITableView` and you can make the look just like a `UITableView` if you want. And `UICollectionView` with separate layouts is the only want to switch between layouts using built in animations.

Comment: Here's a [blog post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/uicollectionview-unjustly-maligned/) about creating "sticky headers" (like in UITableView) in UICollectionView